# Handle ClickOnce "Cannot Start Application" message

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I have an VS2010 application deployed via ClickOnce.  There a number of developers that contribute to this application, and deploy updates to it.  Unfortunately discipline is not brilliant, and sometimes the project is build to an "x86" format, and sometimes in "Any CPU".  When this is then deployed, if the format has changed the end users are presented with the following error message.

[image]

I know this is happening due to the situation described above - but how do I handle it?

I have tried writing an application that takes off the old version and replaces it with the new one each time it runs, but it never gets to this state, as the manifest files state that the formats are different.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to handle this error when ClickOnce detects it other than referring the end users back to my (ever more frustrated) inbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't handle this error programmatically, it happens before your code executes.

you need to get proper process in place - code reviews, single person pushing build live, build server for faster rollbacks when needed etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I think you're right, and it's a case of the process being followed (and warning messages not being ignored!).  It doesn't help that we've not been able to get the rollbacks working properly either - but that's another tale for anther day.  Thanks for the response.